# Is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{4+i\sqrt{20}},\sqrt{4-i\sqrt{20}})=\mathbb Q (\sqrt{4+i\sqrt{20}})$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I don't know if this is true but it is trivial that the right is contained in the left. With the other inclusion, I think the only non trivial thing to check is if $A=\sqrt{4-i\sqrt{20}} \in \mathbb Q (\sqrt{4+i\sqrt{20}})$

Can we just take the square or A and then do $A^2 - 2 A^2 = -4 -i\sqrt{20}$ and then because we are in fields, we can add $8$ to both sides to get $4-i\sqrt{20}$ and then can we just take the root of this can prove the claim?

Comment: Hint : $(\sqrt{5}+i)^{2} = 4 + i \sqrt{20}$

Comment: @SoumyaSinha But what is wrong with what I did?

Comment: You have $-1$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. Can you take the root of it in $\mathbb{Q}$? No, just randomly taking square roots is not allowed in fields. Only natural powers can be taken.

Comment: @SoumyaSinha But then that would mean they are in fact not  equal wouldn't it? Since you can never really get from $\sqrt{2+i\sqrt{20}}$ to $\sqrt{2-i\sqrt{20}}$

Comment: If a in F then a^2 is in F but the convers is not true.  If a^2 in F (example \sqrt 2) then it doesn't follow that a is in F.  (\sqrt 2 not in Q).  But what you *can* do is $\sqrt(4 - i\sqrt{20})\sqrt(4  + i\sqrt{20}) = \sqrt36 = 6$ so $\sqrt{4-i\sqrt{20}} = 6/\sqrt{4 + i \sqrt{20}}$ so $\sqrt{4 -i\sqrt{20}}\in Q[\sqrt{4 + i\sqrt{20}}]$ so Q[\sqrt{4 + i\sqrt{20}},\sqrt{4 -i\sqrt{20}}] = Q[\sqrt{4 + i\sqrt{20}}]$.

Comment: You cant get from $\sqrt{2 + i\sqrt{20}}$ to $\sqrt{2 -\sqrt{20}}$ but you can get from  $\sqrt{4+ i\sqrt{20}}$ to $\sqrt{4 -\sqrt{20}}$.  Consider $6/\sqrt{4+i\sqrt{20}} = \sqrt{36}//\sqrt{4+i\sqrt{20}}= \sqrt{4^2 + 20}/\sqrt{4 + i\sqrt{20}} = \sqrt{(4 - i\sqrt{20})(4 + i\sqrt{20})}/\sqrt{4 + i\sqrt{20}} = \sqrt{4 - i\sqrt{20}}\sqrt{4 + i\sqrt{20}}/\sqrt{4 + i\sqrt{20}} = \sqrt{4 - i \sqrt{20}}$.

Comment: "that would mean they are in fact not equal wouldn't it? Since you can never really get"... they are equal if and only if you can "really" get from one to the other.  And you *can* really get from one to the other.  Just not the way you were trying to.

Comment: @fleablood Hi thanks for the comments. This question was really to help me with this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803677/determine-textgall-q-and-its-action-on-a-basis-of-l I pretty much done it all but i really need someone to confirm this! I have my exam so i am panicking! Please would you or someone else check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you multiply the two elements you get
$$\sqrt{4+i\sqrt{20}}\cdot\sqrt{4-i\sqrt{20}} = \sqrt{16-20i^2}=\sqrt{16+20}=\pm 6. \label{A} \tag{A} $$
So you have that
$$\sqrt{4-i\sqrt{20}}=\frac{\pm 6}{\sqrt{4+i\sqrt{20}}}\in \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{4-i\sqrt{20}}\right).$$

Note that the first equality in my equation \eqref{A} is not really valid since we are working with complex numbers; the square roots you mention are not well-defined, as you can't really know what root of $X^2-(4+\sqrt{20})$ you have chosen as $\sqrt{4+i\sqrt{20}}$. But since the two possible choice are opposite for both square roots, the product is well-defined up to a sign, thus the argument is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a = \sqrt{4 - \mathrm{i} \sqrt{20}}$, $b = \sqrt{4 + \mathrm{i} \sqrt{20}}$, and $F = \Bbb{Q}(b)$.

You have shown that some polynomial in $a$ is in $F$.  This is not the same as showing $a \in F$.  Too see this, consider that $\mathrm{i}^2 \in \Bbb{Q}$ but $\mathrm{i} \not \in \Bbb{Q}$.

There are two generic ways to attack this.  The first is to find an expression in $F$ that produces $a$.  This is what Arnaud D. did in his answer.

The more straightforward/tedious, but less insight-requiring/-providing method is: Observe that the minimal polynomial of $b$ over $\Bbb{Q}$ is $x^4 - 8x^2 + 36$, so, $\Bbb{Q}(b)$ is a four-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{Q}$.  (We don't actually have to find the minimal degree.  We could look at $b$ and say, "the outer root gives degree $2$, the $\mathrm{i}$ doubles that, and the inner root doubles that, giving degree $8$."  This is an overestimate, but an overestimate will work; you'll just spend more time discovering that some of the powers of $b$ are redundant in the elimination steps below.  Alternatively, $b$ is simple enough that writing down a degree $4$ polynomial is pretty easy: $b^2-4 = \mathrm{i}\sqrt{20}$, so $(b^2-4)^2 = -20$.  This might still be an overestimate, but that won't matter.)

That is, $\{1, b, b^2, b^3\}$ spans $\Bbb{Q}(b)$  If you can find $q_0, q_1, q_2, q_3 \in \Bbb{Q}$ such that $$  a = q_0 + q_1 b + q_2 b^2 + q_3 b^3  \text{,}  $$ then $a \in F$.  Looking at the real parts (and grouping by $\sqrt{5}$, since that number is not rational), this says $$ q_0 + 4q_2 + \sqrt{5}(q_1 + 2q_3) = \sqrt{5}  \text{,} $$ from which we find $q_0 = - 4 q_2$ and $q_1 = 1 - 2q_3$.  Plugging those in to our general form and looking at imaginary parts, we find $$1 + 2\sqrt{5}q_2 + 12 q_3 = -1  \text{,}  $$ so $q_2 = 0$ and $q_3 = -1/6$.  Backsubstituting, we find $q_0 = 0$ and $q_1 = 4/3$.  Hence, $a = 4b/3 - b^3/6 \in F$.